# Incorrect output or won't compile

Tags: java

I am having an issue with a couple of programs - one I am to debug and the other that I need to write.

The first one I am to take a user inputted planet name, convert it to uppercase and then run it through an enum.  What did I do wrong?
import java.util.*;

```
public class DebugNine4 {
enum Planet {
    MERCURY, VENUS, EARTH, MARS, JUPITER, SATURN, URANUS, NEPTUNE
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Planet planet;
    String userEntry;
    int position;
    int comparison;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a planet in our solar system >> ");
    planet = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    planet = Planet.valueOf(planet);
    System.out.println("You entered " + planet);
    position = planet.ordinal();
    System.out.println(planet + " is " + (position + 1)
            + " planet(s) from the sun");
}
}
```

The 2nd one is the output is not going through like I want it.  It is coming back with:

```
Cut Shampoo
```

and not with the info I need it to do - be sortable by name of service, cost and time.  Where did I go wrong on this code?

1. First you will need to create a Service object with three data fields.
2. Next you will need to create an array of 6 Service objects, populating them with the data from table 9.6, page 420 in the book, like:

   ```
   service[0] = new Service("Cut",8.00,15);
   ```
3. Using the Scanner object, collect the response from the question: `"Sort services by (S)ervice, (P)rice, or (T)ime"`
4. Return all of the information in 3 formatted columns listed in the correct order based on the input like:

   Sorted by time:

   ```
   Trim          $6.00    5 minutes
   Shampoo        $4.00    10 minutes
   ```

Code:

```
public class SalonReport {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // services listing with time and cost
    Service[] myService = new Service[6];
    myService[0] = new Service("Cut", 8.00, 15);
    myService[1] = new Service("Shampoo", 4.00, 10);
    myService[2] = new Service("Manicure", 18.00, 30);
    myService[3] = new Service("Style", 48.00, 55);
    myService[4] = new Service("Permanent", 18.00, 35);
    myService[5] = new Service("Trim", 6.00, 5);
    SortDescription(myService, myService.length);
    System.out.println(myService[0].getServiceType() + " "
            + myService[1].getServiceType());
}

public static void SortDescription(Service[] array, int len) {
    int a;
    int b;
    Service temp;

    for (a = 0; a < len; ++a)
        for (b = 0; b < len - 1; ++b) {

            if (array[b].getServiceType().compareTo(
                    array[b + 1].getServiceType()) > 0)
                ;
            {
                temp = array[b];
                array[b] = array[b + 1];
                array[b + 1] = temp;

            }

        }

}
}

class Service {

// declaring parameters
String servDescript;
double price;
int avgMin;

public Service(String s, double p, int m) { // constructor
    servDescript = s;
    price = p;
    avgMin = m;

}

// method returning requested item -

public String getServiceType() {
    return servDescript;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public int getMinutes() {
    return avgMin;
}
}
```

Comment: Please solve all of my problems for me please, here they are. No thanks.

Comment: *Where did I go wrong on this code?* When you made no credible attempt to debug it.

Comment: What did I do wrong? : you just don't tell us what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

First seems to be:

```
planet = Planet.valueOf(input.nextLine().toUpperCase());
```

Remove this line, since you cant put String to enum type variable:

```
    planet = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```

Edit:

```
public class DebugNine4 {
enum Planet {
    MERCURY, VENUS, EARTH, MARS, JUPITER, SATURN, URANUS, NEPTUNE
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a planet in our solar system >> ");

    Planet planet = Planet.valueOf(input.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase());
    System.out.println("You entered " + planet);

    int position = planet.ordinal();
    System.out.println(planet + " is " + (position + 1)
            + " planet(s) from the sun");
}
}
```

Above code works, watch out for your input.

Tried combinations like: mArS, mars, Mars etc.

Comment: When I do that, I get this error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to DebugNine4.Planet
 The method valueOf(String) in the type DebugNine4.Planet is not applicable for the arguments (DebugNine4.Planet)

 at DebugNine4.main(DebugNine4.java:16)

Answer (score 0):

For the second task:
It prints exactly what you code, first and second service in your array.
To print all items, cycle through them and printout all fields needed.
Consider using [`Arrays.sort(array, comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) if sorting is not the task itself.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DebugNine4 {
    enum Planet {MERCURY, VENUS, EARTH, MARS, JUPITER, SATURN, URANUS, NEPTUNE};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

              Planet planet;
              String userEntry;
              int position;
              int pos;
              int comparison;
              Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
              System.out.print("Enter a planet in our solar system >> ");
              userEntry = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
              planet = Planet.valueOf(userEntry);
              System.out.println("You entered " + planet);
              pos =  planet.ordinal();
              System.out.println(planet + " is " + (pos + 1) + " planet(s) from the sun");
           }
        }
```